# How to set value for position to scroll horizontally with respect to client width

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here in code to scroll div horizontally, div is scrolled to disappear.
trying to figure out how to make it scrollable only inside width of container

https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-morning-qe9s9?file=/src/App.js:0-1188

````
const quickAndDirtyStyle = {
  width: "200px",
  height: "200px",
  background: "#FF9900",
  color: "#FFFFFF",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};

const DraggableComponent = () => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0 });
  const ref = useRef();

  // Monitor changes to position state and update DOM
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.style.transform = `translate(${position.x}px)`;
    }
  }, [position]);

  // Update the current position if mouse is down
  const onMouseMove = (event) => {
    if (pressed) {
      setPosition({
        x: position.x + event.movementX //needed help here-trying to fix the scroll inside container
      });
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      style={quickAndDirtyStyle}
      onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
      onMouseDown={() => setPressed(true)}
      onMouseUp={() => setPressed(false)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setPressed(false)}
    >
      <p>{pressed ? "Dragging..." : "Press to drag"}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DraggableComponent; ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could put an additional wrapper around your element that is draggable and calculate the width of that element and use it to compare it with the next position of the element.

The starting X position goes from the left top corner of the draggable element, so the last possible X position should fufill condition **`nextXPosition + elementWidth <= containerWidth` and `nextXPosition <= 0`**.

Here's the working codesandbox example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-margulis-782xn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am trying in typesctipt :https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cache-iqg07?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I have already provided the working example for the question. 
Does that cover what you wanted?

Comment: how to make it work if more number of p elements added? https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-cache-iqg07?file=/src/App.tsx